# Is there a better (less-redundant) way to include dependencies

Tags: requirejs

Is there any way to get rid of the redundant-ness of this? When you have dozens of dependencies it looks super janky.

```
define(['a', 'exports'], function(a, exports) {
});
```

Comment: what's the ideal syntax you're looking for? And do you mean that a single module has dozens of dependencies?

Comment: yes one single module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an [alternative approach:](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar)

```
define(function(require) {

var a = require('a')
var exports = require('exports')

..

})
```

Comment: I saw that in the doc. Didn't really think about using it till now, thanks.